# Typescript: excess object property checking for external library

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a function notify from an external library.

This gets declared in the library as

```js
// library.js
export declare const notify: {
    (args: NotificationsOptions | string): void;
    close(id: unknown): void;
};
```

Now I want to call it with args that extend the original ones.
So e.g. like

```
// myFile.js
import { notify } from 'library';

const originalArgs = { /* object of type NotificationsOptions */ };
notify(originalArgs); // works
notify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' }); // ts error message "Argument type {..., additionalProperty: string } is not assignable to parameter type NotificationsOptions | string"
```

So far that's clear, but I want to know best practice to solve this.

My ideas so far:

```
// myFile.js

// 1. typecast with "as" notation:
import { notify } from 'library';
notify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' } as NotificationOptions); // works, but unclean since it's not really of this type?

// 2. disabling inspection with ts-ignore
// works, but unclean?

// 3. disabling inspection by passing in as a predefined const:
import { notify } from 'library';
const extendedArgs = { ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' };
notify(extendedArgs); // works, but unclean, since just doesn't get checked? would say even worse than 2., since it gets only implicitly disabled

// 4. redeclare notify:
import { notify } from 'library';
declare const notify: {
  (args: NotificationOptions & { additionalProperty: string}): void;
}; // error "Import declaration conflicts with local eclaration of 'notify'
notify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' });

// 5. don't use import
declare const notify: {
  (args: NotificationOptions & { additionalProperty: string}): void;
}; 
notify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' }); // no typescript error, but runtime error "notify is not defined"

// 6. declare extendedNotify
// would probably be my preferred solution, but don't know, how to make it work
import { notify } from 'library';
declare const extendedNotify: {
  (args: NotificationOptions & { additionalProperty: string }): void;
};
notify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' }) as extendedNotify; // unresolved type extendedNotify
```

Comment: I think you can just create `const extendedNotify = notify` at runtime, but give it a type annotation that explicitly allows extended properties (since excess properties are not a type error it will work)... it looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4nnKN) (the ts playground doesn't do multi-file examples so I had to simulate importing, but it should work the same).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that was the missing piece - works as a charm and is the solution I was looking for. 
Will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) is more of a linter feature warning you of a potential mistake and not a type safety feature warning you of a potential runtime explosion; TypeScript object types are not sealed or "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)) so you can always add properties without violating the type.

That means `NotificationsOptions & { additionalProperty: string }` is assignable to `NotificationOptions` and therefore any function that accepts `NotificationOptions` should safely accept `NotificationsOptions & { additionalProperty: string }`.  All of this is saying that `notify` is already a function of the right type, but you just want the compiler not to complain about excess properties if you pass in `additionalProperty`.

---

One way to do this is to assign `notify` to a variable named `extendedNotify` which has been [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with the type you want:

```
const extendedNotify: (
  args: (NotificationsOptions & { additionalProperty: string })
) => void = notify; // okay
```

That assignment succeeds because `notify` accepts `NotificationsOptions` and it should safely accept any subtype of `NotificationsOptions` including `NotificationsOptions & {...}`.

And now you can call `extendedNotify()` as desired:

```
extendedNotify({ ...originalArgs, additionalProperty: 'Foo' }); // okay
```

And there's no excess property warning because the property is known to `extendedNotify()`'s parameter type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true&ts=4.8.4&ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=72#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHszBsBcvogDOA8gA4HHIDeAUMsnAFzJFhSgDmtAvrQCYQEAGzhQUCQm2QhM2AJ4s6DABRjORFhiw48lUhWBTkAH1bsuAShYA3dMH4BueshHoiEFQ5YBXEAGtZAHcQa2Q7B2ceZ1oAeljkCBtoeTAACy5kACMIGHRxZHTgImRhUBRi5AArH2kwdFZgAFsfUUhCtJQ84WF0IK44hOayfLAaGTkYeQAaNEncfCNicn1kHmQYKHQm5AByMqyoMXld2jPBETEJKTH84E5QOGEAQSgNLXm9JYN9GMliMYQAAekBAgn42gULDUb00yBUkN0iykK2+yAAZOM4Px+MBKE8AApbMjQMCKcwcECcNaWSzIAC8AD5wvZ+AyJjp5DFgaDwYj5CpqMgAHSiu4PEBPV4aWbY3H44RE9AkqBkli7ABi6HQuxpjmQ8WQ6H8cHkQA)